# Centering two divs in a div: one of fixed width and the other of variable width/height

Tags: css, html, centering

I have a situation where I have one `div` of fixed width, containing an image pulled from Twitter, and another `div` of variable width containing user text of variable length. What I want to achieve is something like the following:

[image]

I can do this well enough with a single `div` that has `background-image` and `padding-left`. But I want to be able to apply `border-radius` to the img element, which simply won't be possible with a `background-image`.

If I do `text-align: center` on the outer `div`, it gets me halfway there. **[Here's a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/joshsmith/uPPTM/)** and a screenshot:

[image]

But this obviously isn't fully what I want.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask and you shall receive — a simplified [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fKxEt/):

[image: jsFiddle Screenshot]

*As an added bonus, the text is vertically centered too!*

**HTML:**

```
<div class="logo">
    <div class="logo-container">
        <img src="http://img.tweetimag.es/i/appsumo_b.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="logo-name">
        AppSumo is a really really long title that continues down the page
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.logo {
    background-color: #eee;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 600px;
}

.logo-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 75px;
}

.logo-name {
    font: bold 28px/115% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding-left: 85px;
}
```

Comment: Just a note that this won't work in IE7. Not that I think IE7 should be supported anymore.

Comment: The only part that doesn't work in IE7 is the vertical centering – is that what you're referring to? The rest of the example [works perfectly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dzbxu.png).

Answer (score 1):

Would it be something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/uPPTM/6/

```
.logo {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: red;
}
.logo-container {
    border: 1px solid gold;
    width:73px;
    height: 73px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle; 
}
.logo-name {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Its a good idea to post your code in your answer. That way when your fiddle goes away (they do eventually!) this answer can still help other people.

Answer (score 0):

You can float the image container (or image itself without the container) to the left, clearing anything the left... and then float the text to the left, clearing anything to the right.

```
.logo-container{
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
.logo-name{
    float:left;
    clear:right;
}
```

You can adjust the distance of the text using margins.

```
.logo-name{
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning with a left position to push the title text past the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/uPPTM/9/

```
.logo { width: 50px; }
.title { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 50px;
    font-size: 32px; 
    text-align: center; 
}
img {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```
<div class="logo">
    <div class="logo-container">
        <img src="http://img.tweetimag.es/i/appsumo_b.png">
    </div>
    <div class="logo-name">AppSumo</div>
</div>
```